# Choosing method to display Chart style data in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-4.0, datagridview, datatable

I am writing an application that will basically allow the user to schedule software downloads (via either http/svn/ftp/mercurial/etc) at certain times per day, to various directories, etc.

I would like to display each "download process" they have scheduled in some type of graph, but as I am new to using the Data controls, I would like some feedback on this.

My initial thought is to use SQLite for data storage, and the DataGridView control. Would this be simple enough, or would there be a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataGridView is the most straightforward approach, especially for a developer new to data controls.

My personal preference for your solution would be to utilize the ListView control and create a form similar to what you see in the the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thank you very much. I opted to go ahead and go with SQLite Database and DataGridView and its working excellent :)